# http post request from angularJS to SpringBoot retries automatically if response takes longer

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, http, tomcat

We are using AngularJs(1.5.8) and Spring-boot in our application. we build these as a single war file and deployed in tomcat server. 
we are consuming the spring-boot API from Angularjs through HTTP Post request. The issue is when the response takes more than 120 seconds or 200 seconds (this time is not consistent), automatically a new request is triggered from the browser which causes some duplicate issue in Server. The browser is considering only the latest request even if we got the response for the previous request.

Comment: It is very hard to understand from the description.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for your reply.
 From AngularJs we do API call ($http post) to Spring boot rest service. if the service takes longer to return the response (120 or 200 seconds), Again the same request is posted without user intention.

var req = {
method: 'POST', url: 'someurl', data: somedate}
$http(req);